# Через php выполнить ssh команду

Tags: debian

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как через php скрипт можно выполнить ssh команду (создания папки, например) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется не «ssh команда», а shell команда. Имейте в виду что это не безопасно, особенно если вы собираетесь выполнять произвольные команды полученные от посетителя, или подставлять в команду данные полученные от посетителя. Например для создания директории в php есть специальная функция с немудрящим названием [mkdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php).

Если вы всё-же хотите выполнять произвольные команды в шеле то вы можете воспользоваться функцией [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) или [shell-exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php). Не поленитесь так-же почитать про функцию [escapeshellcmd()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

И я вас предупреждаю: неосторожное использование (а мне кажется что вы, простите, недостаточно опытны для того что-бы использовать их осторожно (или что-бы от вашей осторожности был какой-то прок)) подобных функций само по-себе весьма опасно, но помимо этого нужно так-же учитывать что их реализация может содержать в себе совершенно непредсказуемые сюрпризы. В общем не говорите потом что вас не предупреждали.

Comment: Это вопрос на форум [ХэшКод](http://hashcode.ru/).

Comment: С хэшкода меня направляют сюда :)@MrClon, спасибо большущее вам за ответ и за предостережение. По поводу мер безопасности я осведомлён, никаких данных от пользователей подставлять не собираюсь. Я просто хочу написать небольшой скриптик, который бы автоматизировал действия, указанные в этой статьеhttp://start.besthost.by/post/5и дополнительно создавал под каждый сайт своего пользователя

Comment: @e-gragor, если этот скрипт не будет доступен через web, а будет запускаться чрез ssh, то над безопасностью (со стороны самого скрипта) можно не заморачиваться. С другой стороны тогда логичнее кажется написать этот скрипт на bash (ну или pyhon/perl, но для таких простых вещей bash сподручней).